# What does it mean to have more neurons than bits in the input layer in TensorFlow?

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, tensorflow2.0

I am creating a model like this to input 32 bit integers into my nn:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(32, input_dim=32, activation='relu'))
```

From what I know now there are 32 neurons (one for each bit). The output of each neuron is -1 if the bit is 0 and 1 if it is 1.

I wondered that it's also possible to do this:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(40, input_dim=32, activation='relu'))
```

Now I have 40 neurons for 32 bits. It runs fine. But why does it work and what does it mean?

Edit: I'll try to explain it a little further. I want to input a 32 bit unsigned integer. So I have 32 bits. When I have 32 neurons in the features/input layer it's very easy:

```
bit 0 goes into neuron 0
bit 1 goes into neuron 1
...
bit 31 goes into neuron 31
```

Now when I have 32 bits and 40 neurons it looks like this:

```
bit 0 goes into neuron 0
bit 1 goes into neuron 1
...
bit 31 goes into neuron 31
What goes into neuron 32?
```

On [playground.tensorflow.org](https://playground.tensorflow.org) you can see stuff like sin(x1) in the features layer. I want to know how exactly these values are calculated.

Comment: "The output of each neuron is -1 if the bit is 0 and 1 if it is 1." Huh? Where did you get this idea from?

Comment: @xdurch0 Can you correct me?

Comment: @xdurch0 I got it from https://playground.tensorflow.org  The color is between orange and blue. Orange means -1 and blue means +1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having more neurons than bits in the input layer in TensorFlow means that the neural network is designed to have more nodes in the first layer than the number of input features. This can be useful in certain cases, such as when trying to capture complex relationships between inputs, or when dealing with high-dimensional data where many input features may be correlated or redundant.

When you have more neurons in the input layer than the number of input features, the extra neurons will receive zero values as inputs. These extra neurons can be thought of as "dummy neurons" that do not contribute any meaningful information to the network, but do not harm the network's performance either.

In your example, the first 32 neurons in the input layer will receive the input bits, and the remaining 8 neurons will receive zero values. These extra neurons may not be useful in this case, but they do not cause any harm to the network's performance either.

Regarding your question about functions like sin(x1) in the input layer, these are not directly related to the input values but are instead functions of the input values. In this case, sin(x1) would take the value of the sine function applied to the first input feature, x1. The function would be evaluated for each input sample and the resulting values would be fed into the network as inputs. This can be useful for certain types of data where transforming the input features can help the network better capture the underlying relationships in the data.

Comment: Great answer. Can you provide reference to a documentation that the additional neurons (in my case 8 neurons) are initialized to zero?

Comment: Sure! In Keras, the default initialization for the weights of the Dense layer is typically the Glorot uniform initialization, also known as Xavier initialization. According to the Keras documentation (https://keras.io/api/layers/initializers/), the Xavier initialization strategy samples weights from a uniform distribution centered around zero.